# Protractor test's within Webstorm has no Browser Connection

Tags: protractor, webstorm

While trying to start the default protractor tests, WebStorm or protractor can not launch the default pages inside the Browser.
The Error Message is a simple Exception:
FA Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
[image: Connection Refused]

The setup for protractor is as follows:
[image: Setup]

The protractor.conf.js is as follows

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    '*.js'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/app/',
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

and the tests are the default webstorm tests.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration looks OK.
Please make sure you have started the local webserver on port 8000 (`npm start`) prior to running protractor - webserver needs to be serving up the application, so that Protractor can interact with it.
Also, make sure that web driver is installed (`npm run update-webdriver`)

Comment: hmm.. and why should it be shown as used? Do you use config module and these functions in particular anywhere in your code?